# Can not Detect User Event / Activity on Firebase for last 30 minutes

Tags: android, firebase

I have installed firebase SDK on my Unity-Android Project.

However, when I launch the game, I cant see user events (**i.e how many user in the last 30 minutes)** in the firebase console. Moreover, Only 1 user installs firebase SDK, it's only me.

[image]

Two thing I did:

**first,**

Disable below permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**second,**

Migrate to `AndroidX` when building in Native Android Project.

Are the above thing prevent me to see any user event?

Comment: I can see this stats even when my app doesn't have any kind of location permission

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA do you have any idea why i cant see any event? it's because of `androidX` migration?

Comment: No I don't think that would be the case. Just make sure the google-services.json file is correct and you are initializing the Firebase SDK correctly. There is another debug view option maybe try using that. Will add more info if I think of some problem

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA the last time, i just add firebase SDK with no initialization then it can detect user in firebase setup page. but now, it failed.